# adding analyzers to Azure Search Index using REST API not saving

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

Having trouble getting the **analyzers** to save / update on the index. When creating, everything else (the tokenFilters, tokenizers, fields) saves fine, but the analyzers array is always empty?

```
 await client.createOrUpdateIndex(index, { allowIndexDowntime: true });
```

Creating a new index:

```
let index = {
    name: "test-index",
    tokenizers: [{
      "odatatype": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.StandardTokenizerV2",
      "name": "test_standard_v2",
      "maxTokenLength": 255
    }],
    fields: [{
      "name": "metadata_storage_path",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "facetable": false,
      "filterable": false,
      "key": true,
      "retrievable": true,
      "searchable": false,
      "sortable": false,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    }, {
      'name': 'metadata_storage_name',
      'type': 'Edm.String',
      'facetable': false,
      'filterable': false,
      'key': false,
      'retrievable': true,
      'searchable': true,
      'sortable': false,
      'synonymMaps': [],
      'fields': [],
    },
    {
      "name": "partialName",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "retrievable": false,
      "searchable": true,
      "filterable": false,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "searchAnalyzer": "standardCmAnalyzer",
      "indexAnalyzer": "filename_analyzer"
    }],
    tokenFilters: [{
      "name": "nGramCmTokenFilter",
      "odatatype": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.NGramTokenFilterV2",
      "minGram": 3,
      "maxGram": 20
    }],
    analyzers: [{
      "name": "standardCmAnalyzer",
      "odatatype": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
      "tokenizer": "test_standard_v2",
      "tokenFilters": ["lowercase", "asciifolding"]
    },
    {
      "name": "filename_analyzer",
      "odatatype": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
      "tokenizer": "test_standard_v2",
      "tokenFilters": [
        "nGramCmTokenFilter"
      ]
    }],
  };
```

Then creating it:

```
await client.createOrUpdateIndex(index, { allowIndexDowntime: true });
```

I noticed no error messages being returned.

EDIT:

Using the sdk @azure/search-documents ^11.1.0

Comment: Your JSON is invalid with multiple errors. Inconsistent use of 'name' vs. "name", trailing commas and then you have references to custom bits not defined here (tokenizer test_standard_v2"). Start with a valid JSON file so others can test your example. I tried fixing the JSON, but I had to give up. Also, test with Postman and you will see some 400 error in the response. The error checking is very detailed and specific.

Comment: @proggrock Are you using the Javascript SDK for Azure Cognitive Search? If so, what version? Please edit your question to include this information so we can better assist you.